# Detecting internal or external devices in event tap

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cgeventtap

I am using an event tap in a Mac app to detect key presses and mouse movements. For the next step I would like to distinguish between an internal keyboard/trackpad and an external keyboard/mouse/trackpad. Does any one have any idea how to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219623/device-information-from-nsevent-cgevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the DDHidLib instead. If you want an example, check out this Open Source application:

https://github.com/FeeJai/MultiLayout